# JMS 2.0: Shared-Durable-Consumer on Topic vs Asynchronous-Consumer on Queue; Ref. Official GlassFish 4.0 docs/javaee-tutorial Java EE 7

Tags: jms, glassfish-4, java-ee-7

Ref: Official GlassFish 4.0 docs/javaee-tutorial Java EE 7

Firstly, let us start with the destination-type of: topic.
As per GlassFish 4.0 tutorial, section “***46.4 Writing High Performance and Scalable JMS Applications***”:

> This section describes how to use the JMS API to write applications
>   that can handle high volumes of messages robustly.

In the subsection “***46.4.2 Using Shared Durable Subscriptions***”:

> The SharedDurableSubscriberExample.java client shows how to use shared
>   durable subscriptions. It shows how shared durable subscriptions
>   combine the advantages of durable subscriptions (the subscription
>   remains active when the client is not) with those of shared consumers
>   (the message load can be divided among multiple clients).

When we run this example as per “***46.4.2.1 To Run the ShareDurableSubscriberExample and Producer Clients***”, it gives us the same effect/functionality as previous example on destination-type of queue: if we follow “***46.2.6.2 To Run the AsynchConsumer and Producer Clients***”, *points 5* onwards – and modify it slightly using 2 consumer terminal-windows and 1 producer terminal-window.

Yes, section “***45.2.2.2 Publish/Subscribe Messaging Style***” does mention:

> The JMS API relaxes this requirement to some extent by allowing
>   applications to create durable subscriptions, which receive messages
>   sent while the consumers are not active. Durable subscriptions provide
>   the flexibility and reliability of queues but still allow clients to
>   send messages to many recipients.

.. and anyway section “***46.4 Writing High Performance and Scalable ..***” examples are queue style – one message per consumer:

> Each message added to the topic subscription is received by only one
>   consumer, similarly to the way in which each message added to a queue
>   is received by only one consumer.

What is the precise technical answer for: why, in this example, the use of Shared-Durable-Consumer on Topic is supposed to be, and mentioned under, “***High Performance and Scalable JMS Application***” vs. use of Asynchronous-Consumer on Queue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was wonderign about the same issue, so I found out the following [link](http://jmesnil.net/weblog/2013/06/27/jms-20-shared-subscription/). I understand that John Ament gave you the right reponse, maybe it was just too short to get a full understand.

Basically, when you create a topic you are assuming that only the subscribed consumers will receive its messages. However processing such a message may requires a heavy processing; in such a cases you can create a shared topic using as much threads as you want.

Why not use a queue? The answer is quite simple, if you use a queue only one consumer will be able to handle such a message.

In order to clarify I will give you an example. Let's say a federal court publishes thousand of sentences every day and you have three distinct applications that depends on it.

Application A just copy the sentences to a database.
Application B parse the sentence and try to find out all relation between people around all previously saved sentences.
Application C parse the sentence and try to find out all relation between companies around all previously saved sentences.

You could use a Topic for the sentences, where Application A, B and C would be subscribed. However it easy to see that Application A can process the message very quicly while Application B and C may take some time. An available solution would consist of create a shared subscription for application B and another one to application C, so multiple threads could act on each of them simultaneouly...

...Of course there are other solutions, you could for example use a unshared topic (i.e. a regular one) and post all received messages on a `ArrayBlockingQueue` that would be handled by a pool of threads some time later; howecer in such a decision the developer would be the one to worry about queue handling.

Hope this can help.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is that you can have multiple readers on a subscription.  This allows you to read more messages faster, assuming you have threads available.

Answer (score 0):

JMS Queue :

1. queued messages are persisted
2. each message is guaranteed to be delivered once-and-only-once, even no consumer running when the messages are sent.

JMS Shared Subscription :

1. subscription could have zero to many consumers
2. if messages sent when there is no subscriber (durable or not), message will never be received.